# Single Jenkins instance using multiple Sonar instances

Tags: java, jenkins, sonarqube

Is it possible to configure Jenkins to use multiple Sonar instances?

Currently we are using one Sonar instance for legacy projects (Java 6) and a new Sonar instance for Java 8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, in `Manage Jenkins > Configure System` you can add as many Sonarqube installations as you want in the Sonar section. Then when you configure a job to perform the Sonar analysis you can select what instance you want to use from a drop down list.